# Free fonts similar to ITC Clearface and Romana

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation, web-fonts

I'm trying to test some fonts for my project and I've found **"[ITC Clearface](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/itc-clearface/)"** and **"[Romana](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/bitstream/romana/)"** font adequate for project requirements, I've searched in "Google fonts" and a few other free font sources but I can't find something useful.

Your suggestions would be very helpful !

Answer (score 0):

Well, the obvious answer is to licence one of the fonts you mentioned, if you want something that specific. If you really don't have the budget for that, there's two fonts that come somewhat close in style (not much really)

[Arapey:](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/arapey)
[image]

[Fnord:](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/fnord)
[image]